# Drupal Views Export

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I added a data export to the view and also with glossary mode enabled..

When I filter the view by alphabet and then click on export then it not generating excel file.

Comment: Above issue is solved I removed the glossary option set in the data export display of the view.But now I am having another problem When I go to any alpha page then try to export .. it is generating empty file.. I want to export the whole view...

Answer (score 1):

This you can do by just installing the [Views data export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and could play around the data that you want to export.
This would provide a module to do your desired work.

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML.

Comment: Hi Nitesh,I am using the data export to generate the excel file. But as I am using the contextual filters it is generating the empty file when I filter. I think the problem is with path path/%/mentor..I have just given some path.. I dont no it is correct..And how to set the path...

Comment: I found this link some having same issue with exposed filters http://drupal.org/node/1322816. I have set the parent sort and now the path I dont no it is correct

Comment: @BLPraveen You can try by applying the [submitted patch](http://drupal.org/node/1322816#comment-6756186) as one of the user has mentioned that it solved the issue for him. If the issue solves your problem as well, then you should report it back to the issue queue with status _reviewed & tested by community_.

Comment: hi develkar,I made some changes so that the export file will show only the filter views. And it was working to me..I found this link which was helpful to setup the data export to filter data based on contextual filters http://drupal.org/node/1322816 .. But here I need to enable the glossary option in the data export to work properly

Comment: But the other way did not work to me to show all the views even when contextual filters is applied.

Answer (score 0):

are u getting any data in the view .
If yes then you could export it to csv or excel and get the desired file.
If no data is being viewed the n you need to check the view once again.

Comment: Actually I fixed the problem by making the data export filter the result based on the contextual filters .. but the problem is I cannot get the full view results in the export even when view is filtered